# How do I create the layout for this rotary encoder on a pcb?

Tags: pcb, footprint

I am very new to designing boards and I am trying to do a board layout that contains a [MODEL EN11-HNM encoder](http://www.bitechnologies.com/pdfs/en11.pdf) but I am not sure how to handle the tabs that provide the mechanical strength while it is on the board.

I have laid out the three pins as it shows in the diagram titled "pcb layout" (in the linked datasheet) but there are also two, unlabeled squares in that diagram that appear to be where the tabs are.

My inclination is that there should be holes there, but the diagram doesn't suggest it (at least to me). Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Just make the holes 2.6 dia, plated, centred on the middle of the squares. (You *might* get away with 2.5 dia, and it would be OK but not great to go up close to 3mm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the squares are the holes for mounting tabs.

It's easier for PCB fabs to drill round plated holes than to make square ones.  Often, PCB fabs charge extra for plated non-round holes.  You can use round holes for mounting tabs.  To be on a safe side, make the hole slightly larger than the diagonal (3.2mm) of the recommended square hole.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your inclination is correct. The squares are indeed intended as holes for the tabs to fit into.

Comment: Since there is no hole in the diagram, how do I know how big to make the hole? Are those squares the dimensions of the tabs?

Comment: Huh? The squares (sometimes rectangles) are the holes, and their dimensions are given. And the size of the holes is not the same as the dimensions of the tabs, except that the height of the holes are a tad greater than the width of the tabs. The holes are big enough to allow the kinks in the tabs to pass through.